# Generics vs Base class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm struggling to find out the best to set up my project. I have a GameSessionServer - the class responsible for JSON request handling and the registered handlers .. Right now I have the base socket handler handler (part of class):

```
  public WebSocketResponse HandleRequest(RequestDto request, GameSessionServer server)
    {
        TrySetThreadCulture(request);
        EnsureUserStoredInSession(server.SessionContext, false, SlotIsEngineRNG(server.SessionContext.SystemGameId));

        // custom request handling
        WebSocketResponse wsr = HandleRequestInternal(request, server);

        // save the last handler
        server.SessionContext.Items[typeof(WebSocketHandler)] = this;
        return wsr;
    }
```

Should it be a RequestDto base class parameter or a generic RequestDto??????
In a concrete handler I do casting of the RequestDto to specific type like here:

```
   protected override WebSocketResponse HandleRequestInternal(RequestDto request, GameSessionServer server)
    {
        CasinoSpinRequestDto spinRequest = request as CasinoSpinRequestDto;

        int TotalBetInCents = (spinRequest.SpinType != "free") ? spinRequest.TotalBet : 0;
        JsonResult JR = null;

        CasinoSpinResponseDto spinResponse = new CasinoSpinResponseDto();
        switch (spinRequest.SpinType)
        {
            case "regular":
                JR = PlayBetSpin(spinRequest, server);
                break;
            case "free":
                JR = PlayFreeSpin(spinRequest, server.SessionContext);
                break;
        }

        // set balance in cents
        spinResponse.Credit = JR.BalanceInCents;

        SlotEngineRNG engineRNG;
        sbyte[,] wheels = (JR is SpinJsonResult) ? ((SpinJsonResult) JR).Wheels : ((BonusJsonResult) JR).FreeSpin.Wheels;
        int rsId = (JR is SpinJsonResult) ? 0 : ((BonusJsonResult) JR).FreeSpin.ReelId;

        if (SlotIsEngineRNG(server.SessionContext.SystemGameId, out engineRNG))
        {
            GameSettingInfo gsi = DataBuffer.Instance.GetGameSetting(server.SessionContext.UserGroupId, (int) server.SessionContext.SystemGameId);
            spinResponse.Results = CalculateWheelPositionsRNG( wheels , rsId , engineRNG, gsi);
        }  else
        {
            int[] pos;
            PosHoldersFactory.GetSlotPositions(server.SessionContext.SystemGameId, wheels, rsId, out pos);
            spinResponse.Results = pos;
        }
```

................................

Comment: Base classes are good for not repeating procedure or a process, so if there is duplication and it **isn't** dependent on a particular RequestDto then sure make it generic. You can usually tell if you need generics because of the use of certain properties on the RequestDto that you need to access (if it is just a `Id` field for example then you can put that on an interface and constrain the generic argument)

Comment: It depends on your use case and I don't think we have enough context to comment. Presumably if your current code compiles and works then you don't require whatever methods or properties are on the generic version of your class?

Comment: it's weird that you seem to be writing your own webserver.... i think MS have a built in HttpServer for this...

Comment: No, it's a specific abstraction of the server. It's just an object that listens to incoming JSON requests via web sockets, parses them and finds appropriate handler among registered server handlers. This "server" is just some kind of assumption the gaming server should act - listen to requests and process them by invoking needed handler

Comment: Oh I see, fair enough

Comment: Yeah looking at your additions, it seems to me like there are two ways of handling this, either template method pattern, a.k.a using a base class with specific derivations according to dto. Or the strategy pattern, where you have specific implementations based on the type that you have recieved and you delegate off to a class that way. Both have their advantages here

Comment: OK, I see that if I have the 1-to-1 connection between handler and the RequestDto type, then I would use generics, but in case if the handler can process more than one type of RequestDto, then the base class would be the best choice??? I plan to use the template pattern when building hierarchy of handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you could use the strategy pattern:

```
interface IWebRequestHandler
{
    bool CanHandle(RequestDto request); // assuming the request dto is the base class

    WebSocketResponse Handle(RequestDto request, GameSessionServer server);
}

class CasinoSpinRequestHandler : IWebRequestHandler
{
    bool CanHandle(RequestDto request)
    {
        return request is CasinoSpinRequestDto;
    }

    WebSocketResponse Handle(RequestDto request, GameSessionServer server)
    {
        var spinRequest = request as CasinoSpinRequestDto;

        if (spinRequest == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Incorrect usage of the handler");

        // do your specific spin request code here
    }
}

public WebSocketResponse HandleRequest(RequestDto request, GameSessionServer server)
{
    TrySetThreadCulture(request);
    EnsureUserStoredInSession(server.SessionContext, false, SlotIsEngineRNG(server.SessionContext.SystemGameId));

    var handlerStrategies = this.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => typeof(IWebRequestHandler).IsAssignableFrom(x)).Select(x => Activator.CreateInstance(x)).Cast<IWebRequestHandler>().ToList();
    // the above is poor man DI, you can just put in the constructor ctor(IEnumerable<IWebRequestHandler>)
    // if your DI supports it, otherwise you can abstract the code above to a 
    // static class so it only gets called once.

    var handler = handlerStrategies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CanHandle(request));

    if (handler == null) throw new Exception("Unable to handle this particular request");

    // custom request handling
    var wsr = handler.Handle(request, server);

    // the consuming of the handler can also be abstracted to a delegate class
    // which merely has the responsibility of sorting out which handler to use

    // save the last handler
    server.SessionContext.Items[typeof(WebSocketHandler)] = this;
    return wsr;
}
```

If you need more clarification, just be specific about which part.

Comment: OK, I see now. Thanks